# QtToolBar with underlined shortcut key in button text

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, toolbar

I have a simple Qt toolbar with text only button `Action`:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
  QToolBar* toolBar = new QToolBar(this);
  QAction*  action  = toolBar->addAction("&Action");

  QObject::connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onAction()));
  action->setShortcut(QKeySequence("ctrl+a"));
  addToolBar(toolBar);
}
```

I would like to have `A` in `Action` underlined to reflect its role as a shortcut key. How to accomplish that?

Comment: What if you press the "Alt" key while your application is running? Does it change the text?

Comment: For my test application no. Why should it?

Comment: @vahancho Yes, it does! A single _Alt_ press underlines the `A` and it stays underlined. Can it be done without having to use _Alt_ key?

Comment: @PaulJurczak, I am not aware of any method that can easily make it. But why you need that? I think it is common or even standard behavior, at least in Windows world, that Alt key make shortcut letter underlined.

Comment: @vahancho I need it to save one keystroke each time I run my application. I would like to see the underlines right away, since they help my lousy memory.  
You are right about this being standard Windows behaviour. I just looked at my old MFC application and it behaves the same way, i.e. pressing _Alt_ key displays underlines.

Comment: @Gombat What OS are you testing it on?

Comment: @Paul Jurczak: Windows, but on the machine I have access to at the moment is Qt 4.8. In the details of [QShortCut](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qshortcut.html#details), it says, that on windows, one can change the settings for it. I didn't found it, but the question is, whether you want it to be a user dependent feature or whether it should work in all machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard `QAction` widget (it is a `QToolButton` actually) uses stripped version of its text for display: "&Menu Option..." becomes "Menu Option".

You can create a custom `QAction` widget which does not use stripped text by subclassing `QWidgetAction`:

```
MyAction::MyAction(QObject *parent) :
    QWidgetAction(parent)
{
}

QWidget* MyAction::createWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
    QToolButton *tb = new QToolButton(parent);
    tb->setDefaultAction(this);
    tb->setText(this->text());// override text stripping
    tb->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);

    return tb;
}
```

In your `MainWindow` constructor use it as follows:

```
MainWindow(QWidget* parent=0) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QToolBar* toolBar = new QToolBar(this);
    MyAction* action = new MyAction();
    action->setText("&Action");
    action->setShortcut(QKeySequence(tr("ctrl+a","Action")));
    toolBar->addAction(action);

    QObject::connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onAction()));
    addToolBar(toolBar);
}
```

Appearence of underline shortcut letters depends on your application style.
Here is an example of a custom style that will force shortcut underline display:

```
class MyStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    MyStyle();

    int styleHint(StyleHint hint,
                  const QStyleOption *option,
                  const QWidget *widget,
                  QStyleHintReturn *returnData) const;
};

int MyStyle::styleHint(QStyle::StyleHint hint,
                   const QStyleOption *option,
                   const QWidget *widget,
                   QStyleHintReturn *returnData) const
{
    if (hint == QStyle::SH_UnderlineShortcut)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return QProxyStyle::styleHint(hint, option, widget, returnData);
}
```

Then you should set that style to your application:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setStyle(new MyStyle);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Same here, thanks a lot! I found a similar example in Qt documentation [QProxyStyle Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html). If only we had better search engines :-(